# Import PGP key to windows user for SSIS

Tags: encryption, certificate, pgp, ssis

I have used Kleopatra to generate a pgp key.

In SQL Server I am running an SSIS package that should decrypt files using the above key. The SSIS packages runs as `ImportFiles` which has the identity of the windows user `NetworkSQLUser` because it has to talk to another server to get the file.

When I first ran the package I got the following error:

> Executed as user: VS2\NetworkSQLUser. gpg: encrypted with ELG key, ID XXXXXXXX  gpg: decryption failed: No secret key  Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  3:50:29 p.m.  Error: 2014-01-23 15:50:29.95     Code: 0xC0029151     Source: Decrypt Transaction File Execute Process Task     Description: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2.exe" "--batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt-files \vs3\FTP\Outgoing\20140122_001.TRN.gpg" at "", The process exit code was "2" while the expected was "0".  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  3:50:29 p.m.  Finished: 3:50:29 p.m.  Elapsed:  0.782 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I read an [article](http://globalgoat.com/2012/03/13/create-automated-pgp-task-in-ssis-using-gnupg/) that says in order to fix this problem do the following:

> the service account that I was running the SQL Agent under did not have the certificate registered under that userid. I had only imported the certificate into Kleopatra for the development userid I logged in with and not for the service account. I simply imported the certificate to the service account profile and then everything worked.

I added the User-ID of `NetworkSQLUser` to the key in Kleopatra but I'm not 100% sure that's right!

I then ran the package again and got the following error:

> Executed as user: VS2\NetworkSQLUser. gpg: keyring `c:/gnupg/secring.gpg' created  gpg: keyring`c:/gnupg/pubring.gpg' created  gpg: encrypted with ELG key, ID XXXXXXXX  gpg: decryption failed: No secret key  Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  5:17:16 p.m.  Error: 2014-01-23 17:17:17.40     Code: 0xC0029151     Source: Decrypt Transaction File Execute Process Task     Description: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2.exe" "--batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt-files \vs3\FTP\Outgoing\20140122_001.TRN.gpg" at "", The process exit code was "2" while the expected was "0".  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  5:17:16 p.m.  Finished: 5:17:17 p.m.  Elapsed:  0.735 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I have also tried running the dtsx package from the GnuPG folder.

I'm at a loss as to where to go from here.

If I have missed any information (my first time with SSIS, PGP and certs) then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the library from [Codeplex](http://ssisextensions.codeplex.com/).

Easy setup and even easier execution. Great library!